# Mostrar vista que retorna mi controlador

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendoui

Tengo mi Peticion.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Estimates/ManageProject",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        IdProyecto: dataItem.IdProyecto,
        Homologacion: dataItem.Homologacion,
        Cliente: dataItem.Cliente,
        TipoProyecto: dataItem.TipoProyecto,
        Contacto: dataItem.Contacto,

    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        window.open()
    }
});
return false;
```

Y mi controlador

```
public ActionResult Estimates(ProjectModel model)
{
   return View(model);
}
```

Como puedo hacer para que se muestre esa vista en el navegador? para que se ejecute común y corriente esa vista? o como lo puedo hacer de la mejor manera posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con jquery.post solo puedes realizar POST ajax y dado que tu deseas realizar un POST tradicional lo que debes hacer es simular el POST de un formulario. Para esto creamos un formulario temporal y agregamos los datos que deseemos enviar en el.

```
$('<form action="Estimates" method="POST"/>')
    .append($('<input type="hidden" name="IdProyecto" value="' + dataItem.IdProyecto+ '">'))
    .append($('<input type="hidden" name="Homologacion" value="' + dataItem.Homologacion+ '">'))
    .append($('<input type="hidden" name="Cliente" value="' + dataItem.Cliente+ '">'))
    .append($('<input type="hidden" name="TipoProyecto" value="' + dataItem.TipoProyecto+ '">'))
    .append($('<input type="hidden" name="Contacto" value="' + dataItem.Contacto+ '">'))
    .appendTo($(document.body))
    .submit();
```

Comment: Esa es la mejor forma para hacerlo en este caso? osea que ese codigo que me acabas de enviar debera funcionar, olvidandome de el ajax, debo remplazar lo que ya tengo por esto ?

Comment: Si, había olvidado actualizar la url

Comment: Funciona a la Perfección! gracia por ese conocimiento que regalas amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto :

```
$.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "Estimates/ManageProject",
                                data: JSON.stringify({
                                    IdProyecto: dataItem.IdProyecto,
                                    Homologacion: dataItem.Homologacion,
                                    Cliente: dataItem.Cliente,
                                    TipoProyecto: dataItem.TipoProyecto,
                                    Contacto: dataItem.Contacto,

                                }),
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                success: function (result) {
                                   var w = window.open();
                                  $(w.document.body).html(result);
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
```

Comment: normalmente, el codigo funciona, pero se olvida de toda la estructura que tiene de asp.net mvc, olvida el layout los estilos todo, en este caso no me sirve lo que necesito es que esa petición me envié los datos a ese controlador y ya que el controlador se encargue de ejecutar lo de el no que vuelva al método ajax, en este caso lo hice así porque no encuentro otra forma de enviarle los parametros. alguna idea?